# How would you switch focus to an input text upon clicking an item on a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website that has a dropdown menu and an input box. For user comfort, I am thinking it would be nice to have it so that when the user clicks on an option in the dropdown menu, the mouse cursor is immediately focused inside the input box so that they can begin typing right away, rather than having to click into it every time.

How can this be achieved?

Here is my Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mlynn/jyrbepyz/3/

Thank you.

HTML

```
<section id="heady">
    <div style="text-align: left;padding:25px 70px;display:inline-block;float:left;"><b><a href="index.html">Site</b></a></p></div>

    <div style="text-align: right;padding:25px 70px;display:inline-block;float:right;">    
            <a href="index.html">Home</a> | 
            <a href="index.html">Generic</a> |
            <a href="index.html">Elements</a> |
            <a href="index.html">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="wrapper">
    <br><br>
    <img src="images/blacksquare.png" width="525" height="197"></img>

    <br><br><br>
    <div>
        <div style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;float:left;">        
            <ul class="navbar cf">
                <!-- <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li> -->
                <li style="width:200px;">
                    <a href="#" class="ActiveListItem">#</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>                                                               
        <div class="container lister" style="display:inline-block;float:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Enter a To-do and hit enter">
            </form>
            <br>
            <!-- <ul class="active">
                <li>Work <a href="">X</a></li>
                <li>Sleep <a href="">X</a></li>
                <li>Repeat <a href="">X</a></li>
            </ul> -->
        </div>
        <div class="container lister" style="display:inline-block;float:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;">
            <ul class="active">
                <li>Work <a href="">X</a></li>
                <li>Sleep <a href="">X</a></li>
                <li>Repeat <a href="">X</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>             
    <div class="Category1">
        <!--list items that user assigned "1" from dropdown menu would be placed in this div-->
    </div>

    <div class="Category2">
    </div>
    <div class="Category3">
    </div>
    <div class="Category4">
    </div>
    <div class="Category5">
    </div>  
    <div class="Category6">
    </div>  
    <div class="Category7">
    </div> 
</section>

<section id="feety">
I believe I exist
</section>
```

CSS

```
/*adder*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400, 300, 600);


 * {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


html {
 background:teal;
}


body {
    /*background:url('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/4657039731.jpg');*/
}


a {
    color: #D9D9D9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active, a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}



#heady {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    height:75px;
    background-color:#222;                       /*Back Colors*/
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:white;
    position:relative; 
}

#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:teal;                       /*Back Colors*/
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    position:relative; 
}


#feety {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:darkslateblue;                       /*Back Colors*/
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:white;
    position:relative; 
}





.Category1 {
    background:blue;
}


.Category2 {
    background:green;
}

.Category3 {
    background:yellow;
}

.Category4 {
    background:orange;
}

.Category5 {
    background:purple;
}

.Category6 {
    background:gold;
}

.Category7 {
    background:maroon;
}

/* clearfix */
/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf {
   * zoom: 1;
}


ul.navbar {

  background:white; 
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:gray;
  border-width:1px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 4px;

}


.ActiveListItem:after {
    content: "\25BC\00a0\00a0";                        /*carat and spaces*/
    float:right;
    font-weight:900;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    font-size:100%; 
    line-height:20px;             /*keeps carat in center of text*/
}




ul.navbar li a.ActiveListItem {
    background:white !important;
    color:black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:white;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding:3px 5px !important;
    font-weight:normal !important;
    margin-left:14px;/* got the activeitem centered with the list text this way*/
    margin-right:0px;

}

ul.navbar li {
    position: relative;
}

ul.navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding:10px 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;

}

ul.navbar li a:hover,
ul.navbar li:hover > a {
    background:#a6d0e1; /*Leaving for now, but keep in mind things bold slowly when you change this to gradient*/
    color: #333;
    font-weight:900;

}

    ul.navbar li ul {
        margin-top: 1px;
        position: absolute;
        background: #222;
        font-size: 14px;
        min-width: 200px;
        display: none;
        z-index: 99;
        box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.6),
        0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    }

ol, ul { list-style: outside none none; }

.hidden { display: none; }







/*Lister*/



.container {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

form {  }

input,
ul {
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:"Tahoma";
}

input {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.lister ul {
    list-style: square inside;
    padding: 10px;
}

.active { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

.inactive { display: none; }

.lister li {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #34495e;
}

.lister li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #dadfe1;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.lister li > a {
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #22313f;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.lister li > a:hover {
    font-size: 110%;
    color: #c0392b;
}


.lister li:before {
    content: "#";                        /*carat and spaces*/
    float:left;
    font-weight:900;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    font-size:100%; 
    line-height:20px;             /*keeps carat in center of text*/
}
```

JS

```
// sub menus identification
$(function() {

    $('.navbar ul li a').click(function(){  
        $('.navbar > li:first-child > a').text($(this).text());
        $('.navbar > li > ul').addClass('hidden');
        $('.navbar li ul').slideToggle(100);
    });

    $('.navbar > li').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('ul').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $('.ActiveListItem').click(function(){        
        $('.navbar li ul').slideToggle(300);
    });    
});
    //newList
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ul = $('.lister ul'),
        input = $('input');

    input.focus();  

    $('form').submit(function () {
        if (input.val() !== '') {
            var inputVal = input.val(),
                activeNumber = $('.ActiveListItem').text();

            if (activeNumber == "1") {
                /*I guess the fantasy code goes here...?*/
            }

            ul.append('<li>' + activeNumber + ' ' +inputVal + '<a href="">X</a></li>');
            if (ul.hasClass('inactive')) {
                ul.removeClass('inactive')
                    .addClass('active');
            }
        };
        input.val('');
        return false;
    });

    ul.on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();

        if (ul.children().length == 0) {
            ul.removeClass('active')
                .addClass('inactive');
            input.focus();  
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `var ul = $('.lister ul')`

Go take a look where is your `.lister` and the child `ul` in your HTML

I mean you probably want to target the needed *DROPDOWN* `UL anchors`
using the right selector:

```
$(".navbar.cf li ul li").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    input.focus(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jyrbepyz/5/